# How to switch credentials kubectl?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, kubectl

I use the clusters on different AWS accounts and every time I want to connect via kubectl I have to do **aws configure** .
How to make other credentials transferred to kubectl ?
I think that I pass the **--kubeconfig**, I can pass the credentials, but I can't figure out how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can manage the different clusters with a single `kubeconfig` as well.

all you need change context for each account cluster with single file

```
kubectl config  get-contexts
```

but if you still looking for other approaches then you can create `kubeconfig` for each account.

```
export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/aws-account-1
aws eks update-kubeconfig --name my-clust --region us-east-1 --profile account-1
```

for second account

```
export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/aws-account-2
aws eks update-kubeconfig --name my-clust --region us-east-1 --profile account-2
```

Now if you want to manage the `cluster` of `account1`, set kubeconfig to account1.

```
export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/aws-account-1
kubectl get pods
```